# How to watch output from systemd service?

Tags: systemd, journalctl

I want to watch output from a `systemd` service on CentOS as if I have started this service from console. Yes, I can see output with `journalctl`, but it doesn't scroll to the bottom automatically. So how can I watch live output from service?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
journalctl -f -u mystuff.service
```

It's in the manual:

> `-f, --follow`
>              Show only the most recent journal entries, and continuously print new entries as they are appended to the
>              journal.

and

> `-u, --unit=UNIT|PATTERN`
>              Show messages for the specified systemd unit UNIT (such as a service unit), or for any of the units
>              matched by PATTERN. If a pattern is specified, a list of unit names found in the journal is compared with
>              the specified pattern and all that match are used. For each unit name, a match is added for messages from
>              the unit ("_SYSTEMD_UNIT=UNIT"), along with additional matches for messages from systemd and messages
>              about coredumps for the specified unit.
>
> This parameter can be specified multiple times.

Comment: Can we just all agree that SystemD is amazing?

Answer (score 12):

To add to @don_crissti’s answer, if you want to see just the output of that service, with nothing else, you can use this:

```
journalctl -f -o cat _SYSTEMD_UNIT=mystuff.service
```

The `-o cat` selects an output format that omits additional information (such as timestamps), and the use of `_SYSTEMD_UNIT` instead of `-u` means that messages *related* to the service, but not printed by it (e. g. start/stop messages or core dumps) won’t be selected.

Note that the journal splits whatever it receives from a service via `StandardOutput=journal` into log records at newline and `NUL` characters, so if your service prints output without a terminating newline or `NUL` character for a while, this output still won’t be quite live.